# Error in declaration of function SQL "Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following"

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I try to create a function in ORACLE 11g, but a have this error when i try to compile the code:[image]

The code of my fuction is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION procedure_maestro(@id_user_buscar number)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT DISTINCT nombre_pokemon FROM Pokemon WHERE id_pokemon NOT IN (SELECT Pokemon.id_pokemon as id_pokemon_tiene FROM Usuario,Pokemon,Pokedex,Salvaje WHERE Usuario.id_usuario=@id_user_buscar))
/
```

Thanks for all !

Comment: Did you try taking off the `@`?

Comment: You are trying to create Oracle function with SQL Server syntax. It is not going to work (and you are going to miss SQL Server, at least from that perspective). https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm